# Make the vector $[1,1]$ turn of an angle - $\pi/4$ , with complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, complex-numbers

We have $[1,1]$ and $\theta = -\pi/4$

here is my attempt:

$(\cos(-\pi/4) + i \sin(-\pi/4)) * (x+iy)$ = $(\sqrt{2}/2 - i \sqrt{2}/2) (1+i)$

= $\sqrt{2}/2 - i^2\sqrt{2}/2 $

= $[\sqrt{2}/2 + \sqrt{2}/2]$

I'm not sure if I'm adding up the parts correctly...

For some reasons I end up with only one part in my final vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac\pi4&-\sin\frac\pi4\\\sin\frac\pi4&\cos\frac\pi4\end{pmatrix}\binom 11=\binom{\cos\frac\pi4-\sin\frac\pi4}{\sin\frac\pi4+\cos\frac\pi4}=\binom0{\sqrt2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$1+i=\sqrt{2}(\cos (\frac{\pi}{4})+\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}))=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$

you have to twist it by $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ i.e., you have to multiply by $e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}$

i.e., you would then have $\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}=\sqrt{2}$

So, required vector has magnitude $\sqrt{2}$ and it is on $\text{real axis}$

Your answer is absolutely correct but just to make it look good and to make it more precise....

Comment: Real axis, not x-axis. :)